# Restriction of Special Characters and Alphabets in numeric box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have designed a textbox which allow only numeric numbers other than Alphabets and Special Character.

Comment: set `type=number` or `patterr="\d+"`

Comment: HTML5 `type="number"`.

Comment: it should not show while on submit

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`type="number"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)**, which only allows  floating point number

```html
<input type="number" />
```